# javascript keys and objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a javascript code below:

```
function init() {
   var data_pie = [];
   var data_key = [];

   data_pie.push(10,12,30,40,80,25);        
   data_key.push("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6");        
   g.update(data_pie, data_key);
}

update: function(data, key) {
   var i=-1;

   var streakerDataAdded = d3.range(data.length).map(function() {
     i++;
       return {
         name: key[i],
         totalPlayers: data[i]
       }
   });
}
```

How can I optimize my code to use this object:

```
var data='{"data":[{"x1":"10","x2":"12","x3":"30","x4":"40","x5":"80","x6":"25"}]}';
```

Instead `data_pie` and `data_key` arrays?

Comment: The variable you are trying to use is a JSON object. Have a look at this website and see what you can come up with:
http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to test this (not having any access to the rest of your code), you might try something like:

```
function init() {
   var data='{"data":[{"x1":"10","x2":"12","x3":"30","x4":"40","x5":"80","x6":"25"}]}';

   for(key in data.data[0]){        
       g.update(data.data[0][key], key, data.data[0].length);
   }
}

update: function(data, key, length) {    
   var streakerDataAdded = d3.range(length).map(function() {
       return {
         name: key,
         totalPlayers: data
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Update function should be called once.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear as to why you would use such a data structure but anyway, here we go:

```
var jsonData = '{"data":[{"x1":"10","x2":"12","x3":"30","x4":"40","x5":"80","x6":"25"}]}';
// var cleanerJsonData = '{"x1":"10","x2":"12","x3":"30","x4":"40","x5":"80","x6":"25"}';

function update(json){
    var data = JSON.parse(json).data[0]; // why use an array here?
    // var data = JSON.parse(json) - using cleanerJsonData. 
    var streakerDataAdded = d3.map(data).entries().map(function(d){
        return {name: d.key, totalPlayers: d.value} })
    }
}
```